# PySerial readline Function Occasionally Starts Reading Mid-string?

Tags: python, spyder, pyserial

I'm using Python to read data from an Arduino sensor using PySerial in Python 3. I'm using Anaconda, and within it Spyder to test my code, as Jupyter doesn't work with some of the packages I plan to use.

About half the time, my code works great and my output looks as it should (288 comma-separated values decoded from UTF-8 in a string), like this:

> 135,134,111,111,110,99,111,109,108,107,111,109,110,115,111,109,104,113,109,110,95,110,111,109,110,111,109,108,114,109,110,99,111,108,108,103,111,110,111,121,109,110,108,113,112,111,95,116,116,120,116,124,124,121,127,121,116,112,117,115,114,107,113,112,109,124,111,111,112,114,113,112,79,115,112,112,110,114,114,114,119,118,115,112,119,115,116,109,116,116,114,122,117,114,116,118,115,116,95,116,117,114,145,115,114,114,119,115,114,103,117,114,114,109,115,114,114,118,117,114,103,118,114,112,110,113,115,113,117,115,111,112,115,111,112,107,113,111,111,130,114,109,110,113,111,113,103,111,111,108,135,112,109,111,113,111,112,99,113,110,110,107,110,110,110,118,111,109,104,114,110,110,95,110,110,110,153,112,109,108,113,108,112,99,112,111,108,105,112,110,110,113,109,111,104,113,112,107,95,110,110,109,122,110,111,108,113,110,109,79,111,107,110,103,111,109,109,115,109,108,99,110,111,110,103,111,107,109,121,110,109,108,113,111,110,95,111,109,110,147,110,110,107,113,111,107,99,111,111,110,103,111,110,107,115,110,109,104,110,109,108,95,113,111,109,162,111,108,110,111,107,110,79,111,109,110,105,109,111,110,111,111,109,104,112,110,110,105

and half of the time I get a variety of errors, which I am guessing is based on the fact that it appears to start the readline function after the string has started (just a guess, since the erroneous strings sometimes start out beginning with a comma). An example of this is this output and error message:

> ,127,142,140,136,143,137,134,129,137,135,136,127,136,135,134,139,136,134,129,137,134,135,178,135,131

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WorkCpu\Anaconda3\envs\Python35\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\WorkCpu\Anaconda3\envs\Python35\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/WorkCpu/PyQtGraphSensorSpyderCode.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/WorkCpu/PyQtGraphSensorSpyderCode.py", line 77, in main
    y = np.array(yValues).astype(np.int)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

and another example of error output code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WorkCpu\Anaconda3\envs\Python35\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\WorkCpu\Anaconda3\envs\Python35\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/WorkCpu/PyQtGraphSensorSpyderCode.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/WorkCpu/PyQtGraphSensorSpyderCode.py", line 57, in main
    lineDecoded = line.decode("UTF-8") 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 166: invalid start byte
```

So I guess my questions are: am I diagnosing this correctly? And if so, is there any way to force PySerial to wait to begin the read until the starting character in the string is output?

My code:

```
import warnings
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import time
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

def main():

#This sets the com port in PySerial to the port with the Genuino as the variable arduino_ports
    arduino_ports = [
        p.device
    for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    if 'Genuino' in p.description
    ]

    #Set the proper baud rate for your arduino - which is 115200 (value is set in the Ardunio code)
    baud =  115200

    #This prints out the port that was found with the Genuino on it
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    for p in ports:
        print ('Sensor is connected to: ', p)


    # --------------------------- Error Handling ---------------------------
    #Tell the user if no Genuino was found
    if not arduino_ports:
        raise IOError("No Arduino found")
    #Tell the user if multiple Genuinos were found
    if len(arduino_ports) > 1:
        warnings.warn('Multiple Arduinos found - using the first')
    # ---------------------------- Error Handling ---------------------------

    ##Run the following two times:
    ##for i in range(2):

    #Assuming there was one Genuino connected (ie. the sensor), create a serial connection to that port
    sensor = serial.Serial(arduino_ports[0], baud)

    #Read one line of data from the sensor
    line = sensor.readline()

    lineDecoded = line.decode("UTF-8") 
    lineDecoded = lineDecoded[:-2] #Index -2 removes newline character and ending comma

    #Print the line of data you read from the sensor as a string

    print(lineDecoded) 


    #Set the X and Y variables:

    #Set X values to static values
    x = range(1,289)


    yValues = lineDecoded.split(",")
    #Set Y to the values from the sensor
.
    y = np.array(yValues).astype(np.int)

    #Plot the data
    pg.plot(x, y)


    #Close the sensor's serial connection
    sensor.close()

main()
```

EDIT: I tested the output based on the comment below, and am getting VERY strange behavior in the PySerial output. Here are the results I got from the code from a few different runs (exact same code):

> ['183', '135', '108', '99', '113', '109', '109', '105', '110', '111',
>   '109', '113', '110', '109', '99', '111', '109', '110', '104', '111',
>   '111', '108', '115', '109', '109', '103', '111', '109', '110', '105',
>   '111', '109', '108', '113', '108', '108', '79', '111', '111', '108',
>   '163', '110', '108', '108', '113', '108', '110', '95', '109', '110',
>   '108', '124', '111', '108', '108', '111', '108', '111', '63', '111',
>   '111', '108', '115', '109', '109', '104', '111', '110', '109', '103',
>   '111', '109', '109', '114', '109', '109', '99', '110', '110', '109',
>   '103', '112', '108', '108', '114', '108', '111', '103', '111', '110',
>   '109', '107', '111', '108', '108', '112', '109', '111', '95', '111',
>   '111', '108', '119', '109', '108', '104', '113', '110', '110', '103',
>   '111', '109', '110', '114', '110', '110', '103', '110', '111', '109',
>   '123', '113', '108', '108', '114', '109', '111', '95', '111', '110',
>   '107', '163', '111', '108', '104', '111', '110', '109', '103', '111',
>   '111', '106', '115', '109', '108', '99', '111', '110', '108', '103',
>   '111', '108', '108', '113', '109', '109', '79', '110', '109', '109',
>   '152', '111', '109', '108', '111', '111', '110', '103', '111', '111',
>   '109', '114', '110', '108', '99', '111', '110', '111', '103', '110',
>   '111', '108', '115', '110', '109', '103', '111', '109', '109', '122',
>   '111', '109', '108', '114', '109', '110', '95', '110', '111', '108',
>   '140', '111', '109', '104', '112', '109', '108', '105', '111', '110',
>   '109', '112', '110', '109', '104', '111', '111', '110', '103', '110',
>   '109', '107', '111', '109', '109', '103', '109', '110', '111', '127',
>   '111', '109', '110', '113', '111', '109', '63', '110', '111', '109',
>   '115', '109', '108', '104', '112', '109', '110', '105', '111', '110',
>   '108', '114', '110', '108', '103', '111', '109', '110', '105', '111',
>   '109', '108', '115', '110', '110', '95', '111', '109', '109', '118',
>   '110', '109', '104', '113', '110', '108', '105', '110', '111', '108',
>   '114', '111', '109', '104', '112', '109', '110', '103', '\n']
>
> ['130', '135', '209', '207', '209', '201', '205',
>   '193', '202', '199', '198', '218', '207', '193', '188', '193', '189',
>   '190', '183', '195', '190', '185', '193', '188', '182', '192', '187',
>   '190', '183', '217', '187', '186', '184', '191', '203', '207', '214',
>   '223', '236', '234', '281', '343', '448', '626', '824', '976', '988',
>   '989', '981', '987', '992', '980', '979', '992', '984', '982', '1023',
>   '987', '984', '985', '988', '978', '1008', '996', '985', '983', '982',
>   '972', '974', '984', '987', '985', '1002', '988', '982', '992', '990',
>   '985', '992', '987', '984', '988', '985', '980', '983', '988', '984',
>   '984', '992', '984', '978', '1008', '986', '985', '992', '992', '984',
>   '992', '984', '977', '984', '984', '981', '975', '996', '985', '984',
>   '988', '986', '983', '1010', '988', '981', '984', '987', '980', '984',
>   '982', '985', '989', '988', '983', '991', '988', '978', '981', '992',
>   '987', '984', '1023', '972', '979', '980', '982', '982', '992', '989',
>   '983', '990', '987', '982', '983', '994', '977', '977', '992', '980',
>   '987', '1023', '980', '980', '982', '982', '977', '992', '977', '958',
>   '940', '916', '889', '851', '840', '807', '778', '813', '737', '716',
>   '704', '676', '656', '639', '631', '604', '590', '598', '553', '545',
>   '525', '515', '499', '497', '482', '477', '461', '450', '446', '437',
>   '432', '432', '425', '424', '411', '410', '408', '400', '405', '399',
>   '398', '423', '390', '388', '375', '383', '384', '379', '389', '385',
>   '374', '367', '372', '376', '363', '370', '362', '366', '361', '369',
>   '365', '364', '366', '365', '353', '351', '358', '359', '355', '360',
>   '356', '357', '346', '350', '355', '345', '349', '335', '338', '335',
>   '336', '342', '331', '327', '323', '319', '311', '322', '310', '311',
>   '321', '304', '305', '305', '299', '293', '284', '297', '296', '280',
>   '279', '279', '274', '270', '274', '273', '265', '266', '283', '270',
>   '263', '268', '255', '257', '258', '263', '260', '249', '255', '255',
>   '245', '240', '250', '242', '242', '274', '241', '243', '236', '255',
>   '242', '\n']
>
> ['0', '169', '121', '118', '116', '122', '120', '120', '111', '120',
>   '119', '117', '123', '119', '118', '95', '119', '119', '119', '139',
>   '120', '118', '\n']
>
> ['135', '134', '213', '217', '211', '204', '214', '208', '206', '203',
>   '211', '203', '213', '207', '199', '200', '192', '201', '197', '203',
>   '211', '196', '196', '192', '194', '199', '192', '194', '195', '191',
>   '192', '196', '195', '195', '201', '213', '222', '222', '235', '228',
>   '249', '281', '340', '440', '546', '683', '846', '976', '1023', '990',
>   '984', '984', '985', '981', '992', '989', '985', '990', '983', '960',
>   '905', '859', '812', '772', '788', '778', '791', '832', '865', '900',
>   '952', '981', '977', '983', '989', '990', '986', '993', '988', '982',
>   '996', '982', '980', '1023', '984', '981', '986', '988', '981', '992',
>   '984', '978', '990', '990', '987', '987', '992', '982', '978', '985',
>   '981', '980', '996', '980', '988', '987', '988', '979', '992', '988',
>   '986', '990', '987', '980', '983', '986', '982', '979', '992', '986',
>   '981', '992', '990', '980', '1023', '985', '983', '988', '988', '983',
>   '992', '984', '977', '984', '988', '983', '983', '989', '985', '982',
>   '990', '985', '985', '990', '981', '983', '980', '990', '984', '981',
>   '985', '980', '992', '983', '989', '990', '983', '975', '967', '964',
>   '928', '899', '886', '857', '834', '800', '781', '748', '736', '717',
>   '688', '679', '656', '634', '619', '614', '582', '565', '544', '537',
>   '531', '506', '506', '491', '484', '492', '465', '454', '453', '449',
>   '448', '435', '441', '425', '420', '415', '417', '412', '405', '413',
>   '407', '398', '393', '395', '394', '377', '404', '387', '389', '415',
>   '388', '375', '369', '373', '378', '375', '392', '372', '377', '365',
>   '377', '366', '373', '374', '373', '363', '363', '366', '362', '359',
>   '359', '365', '359', '348', '344', '349', '344', '344', '350', '343',
>   '331', '335', '329', '324', '336', '321', '324', '325', '315', '316',
>   '320', '313', '307', '298', '335', '310', '292', '296', '292', '287',
>   '285', '281', '286', '279', '273', '288', '283', '274', '267', '266',
>   '266', '265', '275', '269', '259', '255', '268', '258', '252', '261',
>   '254', '252', '249', '253', '252', '250', '269', '252', '\n']

And I also got the 'invalid starting byte' error a couple of times. The arduino only has a 10-bit ADC, so that last output doesn't even make sense... anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: I don't think the string of comma-separated values you've given is enough for me to test this... I wonder whether `lineDecoded[:-2]` is causing your issues. Assuming the example at the very top is called `my_list` can you `print my_list.split(',')` and look for `\n` characters in each of the substrings? I'm wondering whether it's sending you back a string with some automatic text-wrapping.

Comment: Followed your advice and am getting very strange output... Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: Just added it - sorry, should've done so before responding!

Comment: As to your very last comment, isn't any value of 1024 in the range you expect? I don't see that being exceeded. Can you clarify exactly what we're looking at here in terms of your code (i.e. which line of code is generating/processing these lists)? The newline character is its own list item, so whatever list you're processing here, just use `my_list[:-1]` to chop that part off, and it's just a list of numerical strings.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I forgot 10-bit went up to 1024, whoops. It's been a long day!

Comment: Oh and as to what I am looking for... I am trying to plot these numbers in PyQtGraph, so I just want to end up with 288 values. What worries me the most is the one line that doesn't have 288 values in the return - why would that happen?

Comment: No no, I mean what part are _we_ looking at? Your initial question suggests that somehow your list is being chopped up into invalid lines. As it is, I don't see anything in your latest edit that would suggest any "line" should start with, for example, a comma, chopped up numbers or empty strings (`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`). Something you're doing _after_ the point that you get the response you've edited in to the bottom of your question is causing it to fail.

Comment: I think we're going to really struggle to debug this over SO tbh. Make sure you use copious amounts of `print` before and after every step in your code to isolate the point that it messes up. The question will be bloated if we try to do this online for the whole thing, take a step back and see how far that approach gets you first to isolating the issue.

Comment: @roganjosh thanks. I'll take your advice and do some serious debugging.